# Multiple ul with single array in ember handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Lets say I've an array with 6 items and I want print them 3 per list

Ex

```
//arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
//html
<div class="first">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish that with ember/handlebars? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing this:

in template.hbs

```
{{#each set in arraySets}}
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      {{#each item in set }}
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

in the related controller

```
import Ember from "ember";
import Collection from "../../utils/collection";

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    // ....

    arraySets: function() {
        var infos = this.get('model.infos');
        return Collection.create({ content: infos }).divide();
    }.property()
});
```

and who does the hard work is the `utils/collection.js`

```
import Ember from "ember";

var Collection = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    divide: function (size = 2) {
        var array = this.get('content');
        var length = array.length;
        var limit = Math.ceil(length / size);
        var sets = Ember.A([]);

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(size, length); i++) {
            sets.pushObject(array.slice(i * limit, (i + 1) * limit));
        }

        return Collection.create({content: sets});
    }
});

export default Collection;
```

I hope that this could help someone else!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to write a computed property on your controller that splits the larger array into an array of arrays.

Then you could iterate through the arrays of the computed property and use a component to display each of the smaller arrays.

I'll leave this as an excercise to you unless you have other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @Oren is saying, you would need to decorate your model (the array) inside the controller and then display the decorated model in the handlebars (as there is no way to perform logic inside the handlebars itself).

So, something like:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  decoratedModel: function(){
    var model = this.get('model');
    return [
      Ember.Object.create({
        className: "first",
        arr: model.slice(0, 3)
      }),
      Ember.Object.create({
        className: "second",
        arr: model.slice(3)
      })
    ];
  }.property('model')
});
```

Then, you can display that in your template as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  {{#each item in decoratedModel}}
    <div {{ bind-attr class=item.className}}>
      <ul>
      {{#each thing in item.arr }}
        <li>{{thing}}</li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```